# How to correctly send multiple url requests at the same time and display the received data in a table?

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am writing an application to track the cryptocurrency exchange rate. The api has separate url requests for each coin. Here is a JSON response coming from the server, to a request for one coin:

```
{
    "status": {
        "elapsed": 2,
        "timestamp": "2022-08-23T06:10:16.417580964Z"
    },
    "data": {
        "id": "1e31218a-e44e-4285-820c-8282ee222035",
        "serial_id": 6057,
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "contract_addresses": null,
        "_internal_temp_agora_id": "9793eae6-f374-46b4-8764-c2d224429791",
        "market_data": {
            "price_usd": 20946.467798282705,
            "price_btc": 1,
            "price_eth": 13.351682485155417,
            "volume_last_24_hours": 7635594314.553516,
            "real_volume_last_24_hours": 6038552423.10257,
            "volume_last_24_hours_overstatement_multiple": 1.2644742944254175,
            "percent_change_usd_last_1_hour": null,
            "percent_change_btc_last_1_hour": null,
            "percent_change_eth_last_1_hour": null,
            "percent_change_usd_last_24_hours": -2.1478472228280485,
            "percent_change_btc_last_24_hours": 0.11113305637977958,
            "percent_change_eth_last_24_hours": 0.0518833986287626,
            "ohlcv_last_1_hour": null,
            "ohlcv_last_24_hour": null,
            "last_trade_at": "2022-08-23T06:10:15Z"
        }
```

I need to send several url requests and convert the received responses into a table where each cell is a certain coin corresponding to a certain url request.

I wrote a model and a service layer, but when sending two requests, instead of two cells in the table, I get one cell that displays data from the 1st request, and then abruptly changes to data from the second request.

The code is given below:

Сontroller

```
final class WalletController: UIViewController {
    
    private let walletTable = UITableView()
    private let service = WalletService()
    private var data: [DataWallet] = []
    private let identifier = "walletCell"
    private var pointSorted = 1
    private let queue = DispatchQueue.main
    
    // MARK: Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
        configData()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    }
    
    // MARK: setUpView
    private func setUpView() {
        
        // NavigationBar
        createCustomNavigationBar()
        
        // LogOutBarButton
        let logOutButton = createCustomButton(titleName: "LogOut", selector: #selector(logOutButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logOutButton
        
        // SortedBarButton
        let sortedButton = createCustomButton(titleName: "Sorted", selector: #selector(sortedButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sortedButton
        
        // TableView
        walletTable.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9381344914, green: 0.9331676364, blue: 0.9246369004, alpha: 1)
        walletTable.separatorColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1599435508, green: 0.185090214, blue: 0.167404592, alpha: 1)
        walletTable.delegate = self
        walletTable.dataSource = self
        walletTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.addSubview(walletTable)
        walletTable.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
            maker.left.top.right.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(0)
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func logOutButtonTapped() {
        let startController = StartController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(startController, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func configData() {
        service.addCoin { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let dataBoy):
                self?.data = [dataBoy]
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.walletTable.reloadData()
                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func sortedButtonTapped() {
                if pointSorted == 1 {
                    data = data.sorted{ $0.capital < $1.capital }
                    pointSorted = pointSorted - 1
                } else {
                    data = data.sorted{ $0.country < $1.country }
                    pointSorted = pointSorted + 1
                }
                walletTable.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: Delegate
extension WalletController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
}

// MARK: DataSource
extension WalletController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = walletTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9381344914, green: 0.9331676364, blue: 0.9246369004, alpha: 1)
        let coin = data[indexPath.row]
        
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = coin.symbol
        content.secondaryText = String(coin.market_data.percent_change_usd_last_1_hour ?? 0.0)
        
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let coin = data[indexPath.row]
        let infoController = InfoController()
        
        queue.async {
            infoController.firstTextLabel.text = coin.name
            infoController.firstNumberLabel.text = coin.symbol
            
            infoController.secondTextLabel.text = coin.name
            infoController.secondNumberLabel.text = String(coin.market_data.price_btc ?? 0.0)
            
            infoController.thirdTextLabel.text = coin.name
            infoController.thirdNumberLabel.text = String(coin.market_data.price_usd ?? 0.0)
        }
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(infoController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Service layer

```
final class WalletService {

    func addCoin(completion: @escaping (Result<DataWallet, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let urlBtc = URL(string: "https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/btc/metrics") else { return }
        guard let urlEth = URL(string: "https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets/eth/metrics") else { return }
        
        let taskBtc =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlBtc) { data, _, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(result.data))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        taskBtc.resume()
        
        let taskEth =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlEth) { data, _, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(result.data))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        taskEth.resume()
    }
}
```

Model

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: Status
    let data: DataWallet
}

struct Status: Codable {
    let elapsed: Int?
    let timestamp: String?
}

struct DataWallet: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let symbol: String?
    let name: String?
    let market_data: MarketData
}

struct MarketData: Codable {
    let price_usd: Double?
    let price_btc: Double?
    let percent_change_usd_last_1_hour: Double?
    let percent_change_btc_last_1_hour: Double?
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this situation?

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: did you checked this link[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553092/how-can-i-construct-multiple-http-requests-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553092/how-can-i-construct-multiple-http-requests-in-swift)

Comment: This is a good article, but unfortunately I could not figure it out, because it uses syntax that is not relevant today. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controlflow is wrong. For now if you call your service `addCoin` function you are calling the completionhandler twice. Everytime you are calling the completionhandler your data array gets set containing only the newest value:

```
self?.data = [dataBoy]
```

The most simple solution here would be to append the data instead of setting it.

```
self?.data.append(dataBoy)
```

and you would need to clear `[data]` at the start of the function.

```
private func configData() {

    data = [] //<- add this to clear the collection

    service.addCoin { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let dataBoy):
            self?.data.append(dataBoy)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.walletTable.reloadData()
            }
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! You saved me! This approach really works. The only thing I did not use [data] = [], and data = [] Now I will think about how to use one request for 10 urls, and not 10 requests for 10 urls :)